# webpack plagin sass loader

Tags: javascript, webpack, sass-loader

I have problem with plagin sass  loader.
i updated node and got an error

`ERROR in ./src/scss/style.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--4-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--4-3!./src/scss/style.scss) Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js): Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Windows 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (93)`

Understand the compatibility issue, but i don't understand how to update the plugin correctly, or I need to install another one.
My assembly is old, to be honest, but it suits me very well

`https://pastebin.com/VpQuQxCpmu` biuld
`https://pastebin.com/3jB5JeZ3`  configs

I tried these commands:
`npm rebuild node-sass npm uninstall node-sass && npm install node-sass npm rebuild node-sass`

Delete node_modules and  package-lock

But if you roll back the previous version of node, then everything works

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the problem is with your version of node not being compatible with your version of node-sass.

1. Check out https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/ and Ctrl+F search for your node-sass version
2. Check out your current node version by running `node -v` from your command prompt.

If the version you have from step 2 isn't supported, I'd suggest changing to the node version that works with your version of node-sass or vice-versa.

Node uninstall/install instructions: https://treehouse.github.io/installation-guides/windows/node-windows.html

To uninstall/reinstall node-sass specific version:

- `npm uninstall node-sass`
- `npm install node-sass@[supported-version-number]`